# admin namespace access error - uninitialized constant Model_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, routes

I'm working on admin namespace, move some stuffs like user, posts resources into admin section.

in config/routes.rb I have:

```
namespace :admin do        
  root :to => 'pages#home'
  #match "/" => "pages#home", :as => "index", :via => :get 
  resources  :users, :posts
end
```

In app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb I have:

```
class Admin::PagesController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = 'Home'
  end
end
```

Below is the error: (full error log here: http://pastebin.com/bwF1bBHz )

```
  >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
2013-06-20 15:50:04.488 [INFO ]  (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:04.492 [INFO ]  (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:04.496 [INFO ] Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 15:50:04 -0500 (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:05.149 [INFO ] Processing by Admin::PagesController#home as HTML (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:05.166 [DEBUG] User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:05.534 [ERROR] uninitialized constant Page
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
```

Do you guys have any ideas why is it? What should I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should put your controller file not to

`app/admin/pages_controller.rb`

but to

`app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb`

and the same concerns views - default view for index action in this controller should be placed to:

`app/views/admin/pages/index.html.erb`

p.s. your log on pastebin differs from what you've posted here:

```
2013-06-20 15:50:04.488 [INFO ]  (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:04.492 [INFO ]  (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:04.496 [INFO ] Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-20 15:50:04 -0500 (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:05.149 [INFO ] Processing by Admin::PagesController#home as HTML (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:05.166 [DEBUG] User Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 (pid:28961)
2013-06-20 15:50:05.534 [ERROR] uninitialized constant Page
```

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry. In fact I put it inside app/controllers/admin folder

Comment: Same with template files in views folder. I put it in the right way. But the problem is still the same!

Comment: I just change the name a little bit to make it clearer, everything I just copy from the log

Comment: show your `lib/controller_filters.rb` - problem is obviously there on the 269th line